# How to let the admin select multiple users

Tags: users

Probably something like that table with checkbox in people menu. Is there something like that in drupal, some API for creating this type of table? It needs to have pager, because i can't load all users. Is there any way, how to achieve this, or i need to do it by my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) modules.

You create a new view of users and you specify which bulk actions you allow to be performed.